# How do i make all the shapes selected, i mean shapes must always be activated so that i do not need to click any shape

Tags: fabricjs

I have tried below code:

```
canvas.setActiveGroup(new fabric.Group(canvas.getObjects())).renderAll();
```

But it selects the whole group as a single entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have a solution, on mouseover I select the element that the mouse pointer is passing by.

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/arL0ghwp/1/)

```js
window.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {perPixelTargetFind: true});

var shadow = {
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
    blur: 20,    
    offsetX: 10,
    offsetY: 10,
    opacity: 0.6,
    fillShadow: true, 
    strokeShadow: true 
}

 var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 120,
        top: 100,
        fill:  "#FF0000",
        stroke: "#000",
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        strokeWidth: 10, 
        opacity: .8      
    });


 var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 0,
        top: 100,
        fill:  "#FF0000",
        stroke: "#000",
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        strokeWidth: 10, 
        opacity: .8      
    });

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e){
 console.log('over1',e.target)
  if(e.target && e.target !== canvas.getActiveObject())
  canvas.setActiveObject(e.target)
})

rect.setShadow(shadow);
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.add(rect1);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/arL0ghwp/1/)